# Ensure string is a hex value with flow

Tags: flowtype

I would like to ensure that a value I get is a hex string. Currently I say

```
type Color = string;
function foo(color: Color){}
```

But I would like to say

```
type Color = '#' + stringOfLength-3-6-8;
function foo(color: Color){}
```

Is there a way to express constraints like this in flow?

Comment: Regex the string to see if it matches `/#[0123456789ABCDEF]+/i` ?

Comment: It's easy to determine this at runtime, and there are a variety of options to accomplish this including using regexes like you suggest. But the nature of this question is whether Flow can provide this guarantee statically, and the answer is no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not something that the type system can express. You can create a type which is a union of literals (e.g. `type Foo = 'foo' | 'bar' | ...`) but unless you can enumerate every possible string, you can't accomplish what you're asking.