# How to define a Hex type in JavaScript using Flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm building a React component which, as part of its props, recieves a value which can be a string to be parsed as hexadecimal color.

I can check if the value is a string type, but I'd like to be more specific and only accept a string that looks like a hex colour, without adding validation logic to the component itself.

I'm trying to define the Types using Flow.js, so my question is:

Is there any way to check this as a Type using Flow.js? And how would that implementation look like?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible with flow, but if all else fails you could add a [custom `propType`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) that checks the prop string with e.g. `/^#(?:[a-f0-9]{3}){1,2}$/i.test(prop)`

Comment: It seems like a hex type is not possible to express with Flow. Refer to a previously answered question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43388250/ensure-string-is-a-hex-value-with-flow